# Failed to connect to pgsql at :UNIX (port 5432): The value of CL-POSTGRES::USER is NIL, which is not of type STRING

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu-16.04, pgloader

I use a docker image (`docker pull ubuntu`), I installed postgresql via apt-get and then want to run the following script:

```
LOAD CSV
     FROM 'geneset.csv' (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)
     INTO postgresql:///genedb?csv (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

     WITH truncate,
          skip header = 1,
          fields optionally enclosed by '"',
          fields escaped by backslash-quote,
          fields terminated by '\t'

     SET client_encoding to 'latin1',
          work_mem to '80MB',
          standard_conforming_strings to 'on'

    BEFORE LOAD DO
    $$ drop table if exists csv; $$,
    $$ create table csv (
        a bigint,
        b text,
        c text,
        d text,
        e text,
        f text,
        g text
       );
  $$;
```

For executing the script I type into the shell: `pgloader csv.load` to execute the code above.

Unfortunately, I always get the warning:

```
WARNING:
Couldn't re-execute SBCL with proper personality flags (/proc isn't mounted? setuid?)
Trying to continue anyway.
An unhandled error condition has been signalled:
   Failed to connect to pgsql at :UNIX (port 5432): The value of CL-POSTGRES::USER is NIL, which is not of type STRING.

; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition
```

I have already installed  `apt-get -y install sbcl gcl` but the error does not disappear. Any suggestions to solve that problem? I ve found out that this problem occurs very often on docker images...

---

Edit:

Can I basically setup a ubuntu 16.04 docker image and install postresql and pdgloader via apt-get? Is my approach ok? I only want to run the database queries locally in the image...

Comment: From where are you trying to run the script?

Comment: within the docker image... `docker run -it <id>`

Comment: Which image?  One you built yourself, or the standard `postgres` image?  How are you running it?

Comment: I built one by myself... one with ubuntu 16.02

Comment: You should edit the question to include that detail and the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on (macOS 14 sonoma) i installed pgloader with homebrew via this command `brew install pgloader` and I fixed the issue by specifying the **password** for both **mysql** & **postgresql** database, so the command that should be run is

```
pgloader mysql://mysql_user:mysql_user_password@localhost/mysql_db pgsql://pgsql_user:pgsql_user_password@localhost/pgsql_db
```

Comment: ok. thanks it was five years ago. I am not sure how to verify that.